# Как сверстать блок линий статистики в виде волны HTML/CSS?

Tags: html, css, span

Только учусь верстать, и никак не могу сделать такую статистику. Она должна быть сделана с использованием span'ов в HTML так, чтобы при изменении значений - изменялась форма, тоесть линия сужалась.

[image: Статистика, которую нужно сверстать]

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Что Вы уже сделали? Приложите код ваших попыток, нажав кнопку "править" под вашим вопросом. Это учебное задание, которое нужно выполнить самостоятельно, и к тому же, пользоваться поиском, так как ваш вопрос - дубликат - он уже задавался пять месяцев назад.